# How Closure is getting applied in this code?

Tags: javascript, closures

In this code, nextVal seem to be remembered by the function but i am unable to understand.

```
var gimmeSomething = (function(){
        var nextVal;

        return function(){
            if (nextVal === undefined) {
                nextVal = 1;
            }
            else {
                nextVal = (3 * nextVal) + 6;
            }

            return nextVal;
        };
    })();

    gimmeSomething();       // 1
    gimmeSomething();       // 9
    gimmeSomething();       // 33
    gimmeSomething();       // 105
```

Comment: How much *do* you understand? What exactly do we need to clarify?

Comment: i know about closures. But i can't understand how closure is working in this code.

Comment: There's an *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* `(function() { ... })()` which creates the closure. `gimmeSomething` is the function returned from that IIFE. Better now…?

Comment: i didn't understand how iife is creating a closure.